# Python Geoip2 maxminddb.reader error in EC2 server

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, geoip, maxmind

Hi I am facing a issue with below code.

**PS : Its working fine with my local machine but facing issues in servers.**

```
import geoip2.database

def get_geo_city_from_ip(ip="103.148.20.109"):

    try:
        reader = geoip2.database.Reader('GeoLite2-City.mmdb')
        response = reader.city(ip)
        city=response.city.name
        reader.close()
        return city
    except Exception as e:
        return None
a = get_geo_city_from_ip()
print("City ####",a)
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import geoip2.database
  File "/var/www/html/geo/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/geoip2/database.py", line 10, in <module>
    import maxminddb
  File "/var/www/html/geo/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/maxminddb/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import maxminddb.reader
  File "/var/www/html/geo/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/maxminddb/reader.py", line 36
    _buffer: Union[bytes, FileBuffer, "mmap.mmap"]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Packages & Version**
Python 3.5.2
aiohttp==3.6.2
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==20.2.0
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
geoip2==4.0.2
idna==2.10
idna-ssl==1.1.0
maxminddb==2.0.2
multidict==4.7.6
pkg-resources==0.0.0
requests==2.24.0
simplegeoip2==1.0.2
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.25.10
yarl==1.5.1

Comment: [Python 3.6 or greater is required. Older versions are not supported.](https://pypi.org/project/geoip2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working after I changed the
geoip2==2.9.0
maxminddb==1.4.1

Comment: I guess python package `maxminddb ` add annotation var type after major version 2

Answer (score 2):

Are you use python 3.7+ in local machine?

Not support annotation var type in python 3.5.

Like error exc info.

```
 _buffer: Union[bytes, FileBuffer, "mmap.mmap"]
```

Use python 3.7+ in your ec2 server, all is ok.

Comment: I already used this geoip2 with python 2.7 . That time I didn't faced any issues

Comment: I can't able to modify the Python version in server. Is it possible to use geoip2 with Python 3.5.2